# Securing Session for login

Tags: php, encryption

I've read a lot of tutorials about securing sessions.
Allot of people are talking about using this:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

But i don't want to use it as some people are using proxy servers.
I have a question about

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

I read that people have issues with this in IE so I'm not sure if I should use this.
Would it not be enough if I just do this?

```
$ID = $user['ID'];
$Salt = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
$_SESSION['ID'] = hash('sha256', $ID . $Salt);
```

I'll store the salt in the database, and delete it when the user logs out or don't do anything for 10 minutes.
And then at every page I'll run a function which checks if the user is using the right id.
Would this be fine or do you recommend something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on any sent HTTP headers.

The browser may send anything in `HTTP_USER_AGENT`.
`REMOTE_ADDR` will give you (reliably) the IP address from the sender (although this may be a proxy).

I'd say your method should be strong enough for the normal case (it would be very hard to guess a correct session ID).

Comment: Thanks, but any other thing i can do to improve it? because i really don't want any one to crack the session ID.

Comment: @Szenis You can get into things like hosting your site through an HTTPS protocol.

Comment: @Szenis You can save the user agent, of course. I just said that this data is not reliable, but a potential hacker has to guess the sent user agent, too.

Comment: @Szenis But please bear in mind that some users want to surf a site in parallel using two different browsers (or using the PC and a smartphone). Your application should handle this user behaviour (unless you're creating a site which holds sensitive information, e.g. an online banking site)

Comment: @ComFreek I create my session in a way that when u log in again the last session will be destroyed so you can't log in multiple times. so i think i can use it